# Drop-down list that populates based on mySQL table names, with added buttons

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I’d like to have a drop-down list that populates based on the table names (not rows) with a submit button that retrieves the row contents of that table and displays it.

There is a Python script that runs on a Raspberry Pi that reads temperature sensor at intervals, creates a table in a MySQL schema based on the device’s host name (if it’s not already there) and then stores the temperature in `tempreading` and the time and date in `datetime` rows.

A PHP script that connects to the database selects the `id, tempreading and datatime` from the table that is defined by its hostname.

The PHP script: getTemp.php

```php
<?php

$host="localhost";  
$username="root";
$password="mysql";
$database="tempmonitor";
$device = gethostname(); 

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

echo "<br>";

$sql = "SELECT id, tempreading, datetime FROM ".$device."";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. " - Temp: " . $row["tempreading"]. " " . $row["datetime"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

The HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function showTemp(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("Hint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getTemp.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<select name="locations"> 
  <option value="0">Select a location:</option>
  <option value="1">Table 1</option>
  <option value="2">Table 2</option>
  <option value="3">Table 3</option>
  <option value="4">Table 4</option>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="View" onclick="showTemp()">
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="Hint"><b>Temperatures will be listed here...</b></div>

<br>


</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

I can get the row data to display for each row if I 'Hard code' it so I think it's mostly there. It's the linking of the dropdown list with the database tables and the button that I am stuck with. This is my first attempt at any coding so it's built mostly from tutorials and many hours reading on w3schools.

04/08/2019
Ok, so an update. I can now list the tables and print them to the screen with the following:

```
$showtables= "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$database."";
$result = $conn->query($showtables);

 while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
  echo($table[0] . "<br>");  
 }
```

How would I change:

```php
echo($table[0] . "<br>");
```

to instead populate a drop down list? I've tried various things with the option value code, but had no success as yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the "SHOW TABLES" sql query. It returns the list of all tables in a database. You can display the results of this query in a select box